# Sending requests to HTTPS endpoint with Netty

Tags: java, https, netty

We are looking for some article where is described a simple way of sending HTTPS requests using Netty. Google shows the HTTP requests samples mainly. 
Could you please point some article or provide any code sample?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java

Comment: Thanks, but this seems HTTP call, while I am looking for HTTPS.

Comment: Just add `SslHandler` into the pipeline ? The example actually also supports HTTPS: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java#L54